# Bean property 'principal.username' is not readable or has an invalid getter method, when I logout and try to go to student/list

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

When I login using spring security, I am redirected to student/list but once I log out and try to access link again I get

```
type=Internal Server Error, status=500
Invalid property 'principal.username
```

It is not finding valid username, but I need to access the login page again when I am logged out, this is my jsp code

```html
<form:form action="${contextPath}/authenticateTheUser" method="POST">
    <c:if test="${param.error !=null}">
        <i class="failed">Sorry! You have entered ivalid username/password</i>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${param.logout !=null}">
        <i class="logout">You Have Been Logged Out</i>
    </c:if>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label>User Name</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="Login"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    </form:form>
```

logout fuctionality has been added in my list-student but once I am logged out I type in my credentials and it gives me white label 404 but when I go to student/list after I get this error I am logged in as the correct user, here is my list-student page

```html
<form:form action="${contextPath}/logout" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" value="Log Out">
        </form:form>
```

the contextPath refers to my configure code

```java
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/student").hasRole("EMPLOYEE").antMatchers("/student/showFormForAdd/**")
                .hasRole("ADMIN").antMatchers("/student/addAddress/**/student/showFormForAdd/**").hasRole("MANAGER")
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser").permitAll().and()
                .logout().permitAll();

    }
```

Overall I need to be able to login and directly be redirected to my student-list, and if I logout and login again I need to have the same functionality, not get a white label 500 or a Bean property 'principal.username' is not readable here is my controller code

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/student")
public class StudentController {
@GetMapping("/list")
    public String listStudents(Model model) {
        List<Student> students = studentService.showAllStudents();
        model.addAttribute("students", students);
        return "list-students";
    }
}
```

my login mapping

```java
@Controller

public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String showMyLoginPage() {
        return "login-form";
    }

}
```

note my login controller has a default to `/login` but my `/list` for my `list-students` has a request mapping at class level named `/student`